# Missing cameras in cameraIdList

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2

halo,

i have an issue with my app i'm trying to get all cameras of my phone.
my app detects only 2 cameras
i'm using :

```
val manager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
var listOfCamer as = manager.cameraIdList;
```

When I tried openCamera (https://opencamera.sourceforge.io/help.html), it detects 4 cameras!
Or we use the same method/class

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                return manager.getCameraIdList().length;
            }
```

am I missing some config / permissions?

Comment: Any updates to this? Facing the same problem. OpenCamera list ultra wide camera with ID 3, but cameraIdList returns cameras 0 and 1 in my app.

Comment: @xinaiz yeah, the answer was the package name ... open camera package name is whitelisted and it can fetch more cameras ..

Answer (score 0):

> (Android 10 or higher) Hide physical sub-cameras from getCameraIdList. This reduces the number of cameras that can be directly opened by apps, eliminating the need for apps to have complex camera selection logic.

I think [this](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera) is the reason. Try the same with old [Camera API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#java) (though it is deprecated now), perhaps, it would allow you to see all your 4 devices.

Comment: thank you for your answer, since both apps are running on 29 api , what could be the reason of having two different behavior with nearly same code  , can't figure out what configuration have shown those aux cameras

Comment: No matter which SDK level your aps are build with, you are free to use both `Camera API` and `Camera 2 API` (available since 21). I have opened Open Camera sources and found out that it really uses both camera APIs depending on use case.

Comment: i used both apis (camera and camera2)  and result still the same only 2 cameras available.. i tried to isolate the code in open camera and in my app and i can't find any difference other than the package name :D this will drive me crazy